# Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: 'CaptionText' is not a property or an existing field

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller, rdlc

i have uploaded project in IIS when i run report which in rdlc it give me this error
**Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: 'CaptionText' is not a property or an existing field.**

In localhost report work fine

Comment: Add a code that causes this exception, including the `CaptionText` declaration. Looks like the  `CaptionText` is a field but expected a property.

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add ReportViewer HTTP handler in web.config inside system.webserver section:

```
<system.webserver>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
     path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
     type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler"
     resourceType="Unspecified" />
</system.webserver>
```